# Differentiability of a function of several variables at $0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The following is a problem from Spivak's Calculus On Manifolds

Q) Let $ f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R $ be a function such that $|f(x)| \leq |x|^2 $. Show that $f$ is a differentiable at $0$.

The solutions given on the solution manuals is as follows.

$$ |f(0)| \leq ||0||^2 \implies f(0)=0 $$

$$ Since \  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(x)-f(0)|}{||x||}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(x)|}{||x||}\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}||x||=0$$ $$\implies Df(0)(x)=0$$
My question is how did we come to the conclusion that $Df(0)(x)=0$ ? Did we just guess the value of the linear transformation $Df(0)(x)$ so that the function $f$ could be differentiable at $0$. Aren't we supposed to check for differentiability ? I understand that if the function $f$ is differentiable at $0$ then the derivative of the function at the point $0$ is a linear transformation $Df(0):\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{||f(x)-f(0)-Df(0)(x)||}{||x||}=0$$ How can we prove differentibility using this definition ?

Comment: Solutions manual?  Who is responsible for that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, using that $|e_i|=1$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ we get:

$$\dfrac{|f(t\cdot e_i)-f(0)|}{|t|}=\dfrac{|f(t\cdot e_i)|}{|t|·||e_i||}=\dfrac{|f(t·e_i)|}{||t\cdot e_i||}\leq ||t\cdot e_i||=|t|\cdot ||e_i||=|t|$$

Taking limit $t\to 0$ we get that: $$\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{|f(t\cdot e_i)-f(0)|}{|t|}=0 \implies D_i f(0):=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(t\cdot e_i)-f(0)}{t}=0$$

Comment: I see that you have evaluated the partial derivatives. I guess with that we can evaluate the linear transformation matrix of total derivative and proof the differentiability at 0. Buts thats not how they did it in the solution manual. They have evaluated the ratios of magnitude of change in range to magniitude of change in domain and somehow concluded from that the derivative linear transformation is a zero map. Do you think what they did in the solution manual is right ?

Comment: A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $0$ if there exists a linear function $df(0)$ such that: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)-df(0)(x)}{||x||}$$ In your case, they prove that if we choose $df(0)=0$, the limit is actually $0$. Then it must be $df(0)=0$, because you can easily proof that in case of existing such a linear function, it's unique. Then i would say that there lacks a bit of explanation on the proof, but it's right.